# Questions about le

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, expresiones, pronombres, españa

****El primero de ellos fue un maestro de pintar panderos,* al que "le" ayudaba preparándo"le" los colores.***

In this sentence, why are there two ***le***?

And what those ***le*** designate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is a case of "leísmo" (overuse of "le") used in many countries. Since that first "le" functions as direct object, it should be "lo", not "le":

... al que **lo** ayudaba ...

The second "le" is an indirect object.

- He helped **him** (direct object) by preparing **him** (indirect object) the colors.
- **Lo** (**le**, in countries where "leísmo" is used) ayudaba preparándo**le** los colores.